# MS Access - ADODB conection issue - syntax error in FROM clause

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, 64-bit, adodb

I am migrating an App designed in Access 32 bits to Access 64 bits. I have followed all the steps defined in the Microsft website. I have managed to open it and work in most of the macros that App had, but I am struggling with an ADODB connection. I update the Library from previous "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" to "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0".

The code open a data base txt file (I include below the structure) and then write it in a Table of the Access database. The issue is when loading the Txt fila into the Recordset. The connection is fine (cnnTXT), but I get the syntax error in the Open step.

Here is the chunck of the code where I am getting the message:

```
Dim cnnTXT As New ADODB.Connection                                      
Dim rsItfProc As New ADODB.Recordset


cnnTXT.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Forms!Menu_de_Opciones!tb_ruta & "\" & strDirItf & ";Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=no;FMT=Delimited"""


If rsItfProc.State = 1 Then rsItfProc.Close
  Dim file As String
  file = URL_of_the_file 
            
  rsItfProc.Open file, cnnTXT, adOpenStatic, , adCmdTable ---> HERE I AM GETTING THE MESSAGE

End If
```

The file is like that:

```
22.11.2022                                             Dynamic List Display                1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Column1   |Column2    |Column3      |Column4          |Valid Until|Valid From|Column5     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|XXXX      |50         |1234567890   |1234567890       |31.12.9999 |01.01.1999|81671454    |
|XXXX      |50         |1234567890   |1234567890       |31.12.9999 |01.01.1999|81671454    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried many things, but I am not an expert on this kind of connections.

I have changed the adCmdTable attribute to adCmdText, I have tried to change the Open to OpenText. Also I have tried to write the SQl sentence as the first attribute but there is no table name, so I am looping around trying things that does not work.

Can anyone tell me if there is something missing or there is a parameter that should not be there?
In the 32 bits version it does work.

Regards

Comment: seems you forgot an `Else` as you're using a one-line if statement, and have an `End If` further down

Comment: Yes, you are right, I tried to simply the code because it is much longer and I included this "End If" which is not correct in this case as it fully evaluated in one line.

Comment: The file has not the right format for a delimited text file. I must not contain any title line or separator lines --------. It can can contain a header which consists of separated column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be confusing opening a recordset with opening the file (Connection to the file)

```
recordset.Open source, ActiveConnection, options
```

Here "source" should be the SQL you want to run. For text files the "table name" is the name of the text file

Comment: But I use as "source" the full path to the file including the name of the file without the extension. Something like: "C:\Documents\TXT_file"

Comment: The full path to the file is what you need to <i>connect</i> to the file. Once you are connected you then need to select the data - and for that you need a query such as `select * from Name_of_File_without_path`

Comment: But I do the connection in the with cnnTXT, don't I?

Comment: There are two steps to extracting information from a data source
1. Connect to the data source
In your case this is `cnnTXT' - and you need the fully pathed filename for that bit because it needs to find the file. You have got that bit right.
2. USE that connection to extract the data.
Create a record set by referring to the connection made, giving the query to want to run, the connection you have set up and any other relevant information as options.
This part just needs the name of the file, because there is no database table or Excel sheet to refer to. This is the bit you have wrong